# Maven + Delombok issue when compiling in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, lombok

I have a maven project in Eclipse that uses lombok/delombok.

When I build, from Eclipse, using a maven script (e.g. `mvn clean package`), everything works fine.

However, when I run directly from Eclipse (say with a clean/build of my project), I have a classpath issue concerning a class that should be present in the tools.jar from the JDK. I have tried adding the tools.jar directly in my project build path, without any success.

[Edit]
The stack trace is:

```
03/07/11 23:39:44 CEST: Maven Builder: FULL_BUILD   
03/07/11 23:39:44 CEST: [WARN] The POM for com.google.code.gwt-log:gwt-log:jar:3.1.2 is missing, no dependency information available  
03/07/11 23:39:44 CEST: Build errors for fiveorbs; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.projectlombok:maven-lombok-plugin:0.9.3.1:delombok (default) on project fiveorbs: Execution default of goal org.projectlombok:maven-lombok-plugin:0.9.3.1:delombok failed: A required class was missing while executing org.projectlombok:maven-lombok-plugin:0.9.3.1:delombok: com/sun/tools/javac/util/Context  
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.projectlombok:maven-lombok-plugin:0.9.3.1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Daedin/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/maven-lombok-        plugin/0.9.3.1/maven-lombok-plugin-0.9.3.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/../lib/tools.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Daedin/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/0.9.3/lombok-0.9.3.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Daedin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
```

[/Edit]

My configuration is as follows:

- Eclipse 3.6 Helios
- Maven 2.3
- JDK 1.6
- Lombok 0.9.3
- Delombok maven plugin 0.9.3.1

The part of the pom.xml that contains the declaration of the delombok plugin is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-lombok-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I apologize if this question seems trivial, but I have been looking for an answer for a couple of hours, and I'm starting to get stuck.

Thanks in advance for any hint you may be able to provide - and please let me know if I have omitted any useful information.

Comment: Is this in Linux, Windows, or OS X? (Unfortunately, it makes a difference)

Comment: I am on Windows. Just to be clear: if I run an mvn clean package from the root using the command prompt, everything works fine. So I would assume the issue lies within the setup of Eclipse somewhere, but I really cannot fathom where.

Comment: I have now switched to lombok 0.10.0-RC1 to solve another issue, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I tried to completely remove the dependency to sun.jdk.tools, and I get the exact same error, which tends to prove that the library is really not found in the classpath.

Comment: FYI: I've got the combination of Lombok 0.10.0-RC1 and Maven 3 running on both Windows and Ubuntu, so it *is* possible, for all that's worth :-)

Comment: Does it work for you within Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, both in eclipse and Maven

Comment: So you must have the solution to my issue hiddent there somewhere :) Would you mind either sending me by email, or linking here, your pom.xml and eclipse.ini? I'm not sure which files may be relevant, so feel free to add anything you think might be related :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure Eclipse is launched using a JDK (not a JRE). To be sure, set the path to the executable in eclipse.ini

on *x systems (probably includind MacOS):

```
-vm /path/to/jdk/bin/javaw
```

on Win*:

```
-vm
C:\path to jdk\bin\javaw.exe
```

(needs to be on separate lines, no quotes - see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example )

To determine which JVM Eclipse launched under, you can use Help->About, Installation Details, Configuration.  Then look for the -vm line. If you see multiple -vm lines, or the -vm line points at a JRE instead of a JDK, adjust eclipse.ini then relaunch Eclipse and do a Maven->Update on the project.

Comment: My eclipse.ini looks like this: 
    -vm 
    C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin'
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx2048m
    -javaagent:lombok.jar
    -Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar'

Comment: @Sébastien -vm needs to point to the executable, not the directory. add javaw.exe to the path

Comment: I did the change, but unfortunately the issue persists

Comment: OK, open the task manager, find your eclipse task and see if it's using the correct javaw.exe. Because it could be that the Eclipse.ini is choking on the space in your java path ("Program Files").

Comment: I have killed and reoponed Eclipse to make sure there were no "parasite" javaw.exe running. The only javaw.exe that was running after I relaunched Eclipse was located in "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin"; so it seems that it manages to find the correct one.

Comment: @Sébastien then I'm sorry, I can't help you :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway :) From the look of it, lombok is properly installed (I can use lombok during development), the maven script is correct (it builds properly with maven), but for some reason when my maven project in eclipse compiles, things are falling apart.

Comment: Just had this problem and the issue was indeed that Eclipse was running from a jre instead of a jdk.  I'm going to add info to the response on how to check the current VM running in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has been solved in Lombok 0.10.0 or higher

Comment: I have stopped using Lombok with maven for my project (either the one or the other), but I'll try once I am in the correct configuration once again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with delombok when compiling on a Linux VM, when the source was using a mounted Windows share. In my case the problem was solved by moving the repository to another location exclusively on the Linux VM, then recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your Eclipse by executing lombok.jar?

Also Lombok requires javac 1.6 or higher

Comment: Yes, everything is fine during development. The issue apparently occurs when the Maven Builder is invoked. I'll edit the original post to add the strack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday afternoon. I am using Java 8, Eclipse oxygen, maven 3.5.2.

**Solution:** 
The issue got resolved by removing the Lombok dependency from pom and by adding the Lombok jar in the build path by downloading it separately.

I also edited the eclipse.ini and added the following:

-javaagent:lombok.jar

I downloaded 1.16.18 version of Lombok jar.